# Mapping properties of different classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a class as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item_info")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Original{
    String sku;
    String productname;
    // few other properties
    // getter / setter methods
}
```

I populate these properties by calling an api (which returns a json) using RestTemplate. Once populated, I need to store it in DB. The problem is, based on some condition, I call 3 different apis. Now, all three apis have the information I need. However, the keys might be different in different apis. For instance, instead of "productname", the key might just be "name".

So, I have created three different classes, each class mapping to an api. Eg:

```
class Api1{
    String sku;
    String name;
    // other properties and getter/setters
}
```

I populate the values of Api1 using something like this:

```
Api1 api1 = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Api1.class).getBody();
```

Now, I need to map the properties of the new classes back to the original class (i.e map "name" of Api1 class to "productname" of Original class). How do I do this? Do I need to do the mapping manually? Or does Spring offer a simpler solution for this?

Comment: Why not make all your classes implement the same interface?

Comment: You could also, if suitable, use the Spring Conversion Service.

Comment: @JB Nizet I'm writing a CRUDRepository to find "Original" object by sku, something like public Original findBySku(@Param("sku") String sku). So if I make Api1 class implement Original interface, how will this work? How can it return object of type Original? Will I have to add all the properties (such as sku, productname etc.) in the Original interface as well?